# Visual C++ 2008 Multimap Deterministic

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, multimap

Does the implementation of multimap in Visual Studio 2008 return the ordering of items with the same key inserted in the same order between runs in a deterministic order?

I have a problem where I need to ensure that between runs, the order of the items with the same key returned by the multimap is deterministic, assuming they were inserted in the same order. I know that the ordering is not guaranteed to be in the order of the insertions according to the C++ 98 standard. However, this is not important for my problem - being deterministic between different runs when the same key-value pairs were inserted in the same order is.

I have written the following test program for a single run where I add 1,000,000 values to the same random double key ( pairs - as in my specific problem), and check the ordering is returned in the order they are inserted. The outcome of this result is positive (the elements are always returned in the order inserted). This is very encouraging - but not a guarantee that it will occur for every series of  key-value pairs.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int testElements = 1000000;

    std::multimap<double, size_t> multiMapTest;
    std::vector<size_t> insertOrder;
    insertOrder.reserve(testElements);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        srand( 0 );
        double index = rand();
        for (int j = 0; j < testElements; j++)
        {
            int val = rand() % 100;
            multiMapTest.insert(std::pair<double,size_t>(index,val));
            insertOrder.push_back(val);
        }

        size_t mapSize = multiMapTest.count(index);
        size_t insertOrderSize = insertOrder.size();
        assert( mapSize == insertOrderSize );

        int j = 0;
        for (std::multimap<double,size_t>::iterator it = multiMapTest.begin(); it!=multiMapTest.end(); ++it)
        {
            assert ( (*it).second == insertOrder[j] );
            j++;
        }

        multiMapTest.clear();
        insertOrder.clear();
    }


    std::string input;
    getline(std::cin, input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The standard requires (**23.2.4** Table 102) that a newly inserted key be placed at the end of the range of equivalent keys. I have no reasons to doubt that VS2008's implementation satisfies this requirement. In any case, the source code is available to you, you can inspect it and/or step through it in the debugger.